# firebase phone auth: How to change code after atime

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I use firebase phone auth in my app for OTP. My problem: while Firebase sent sms with code, I don't Verify this and request another but Firebase still send back same code. It only sends another when verification with code before done. 
How can I change this?
Thanks.

Comment: This is an optimization. If the code is not expired, it will be resent. Once the code is expired and not redeemed, a new one will be sent.

Comment: I know this, so can i set expire time of code?

Comment: No you can't do so.